# Deriving quantiles for $L_1$ using $\textbf{P}\{ L_n > n \cdot a \}$ as n tends to infinity

Tags: real-analysis, limits, probability-theory

Given a random variable 
$$L_n = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i Z_i $$
where $X_i \sim Bernoulli(p)$ and $Z_i \sim \exp(\theta)$. I assume $\{Z_i \}$ is  i.i.d. and the sequences $\{X_i \}$ and $\{Z_i \}$ are independent.
According to Cramér’s large deviation theorem, 
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} \log \left( \textbf{P}\{ L_n > n \cdot a \}\right)  = - \Lambda^*(a)  
    \\
    \Lambda^*(a) = \sup_{\xi \in \mathbb{R}} \left( \xi a - \Lambda (\xi) \right) 
    \\
    \Lambda (\xi) = \log \left(\kappa(\xi) \right) $$
where $\kappa$ denotes the moment generating function for $X_1 Z_1$ and $a>0$. Note that $\kappa(\xi) = \frac{p \theta}{\theta - \xi}+1-p$. I have calculated the $\xi^*$ that solves $\Lambda^*(a)$ 
$$\xi(a,p,\theta)^*= \frac{\theta (2-p) - \sqrt{p \cdot (\theta^2p + \frac{4(p+\theta)}{a}) } }{2(1-p)}.$$
Now, by using the approximation  $ \textbf{P}\{ L_n > n \cdot a \} \approx  e^{-n \Lambda^*(a)} $, I want to calculate the $\alpha$-quantile $(VaR_{\alpha})$, where I think of $n$ as "large" and $\alpha$, $\theta$ and $p$ as given.  Formally, I can get this far:
\begin{align*}
\text{VaR}_\alpha(L) = & \text{inf} \{ x \in \mathbb{R} : P(L>x) \leq 1-\alpha \} \\
= & \text{inf} \{ a \in \mathbb{R} : P \left( L>n \cdot a \right ) \leq 1-\alpha ) \\
\approx& \inf \{  a \in \mathbb{R} : e^{-n \Lambda^*(a ) } = 1-\alpha 
\} 
\end{align*}
where the equality comes from $\Lambda^*(a)$ being smooth. Thus I have to find the smallest $a$ that solves $e^{-n\Lambda^*(a )} = \alpha$ for a "large" n.
\begin{align*}
    e^{-n\Lambda^*(a )} = 1- \alpha
    \\
    e^{-n(\xi^* a - \log (\kappa (\xi^*)) )} =1- \alpha 
    \\
    \kappa(\xi^*)^n e^{-n \xi^* a} = 1- \alpha
\end{align*}
However, I cannot directly solve this equation since $a$ is in $\xi^*$.
How do I proceed?